# Old timer does not stop

Tags: java, timer

I start a timer when the first question appears, it goes back. If the user answers the question in time, I want timer to completely cancel and a new timer to start. However, when user answers the question, in the second question, the first timer still process.

This is my timer method:

```
public Timer myTimer() {
    timer = new Timer();
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sec--;
            if (sec<0) {

                this.cancel();

                game.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(game, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "GAME OVER!\nYour score: " + score);

                scoreJSON = new ScoreJSON(playerName, score);
                scoreJSON.write();

            } else if (sec<10) {
                time.setText("0" + String.valueOf(sec));
            } else {
                time.setText(String.valueOf(sec));
            }
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 1000);
    return timer;
}
```

This is one alternative for user to answer the question:

```
a.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        checkAnswer("answer0");
        myTimer();
    }
});
```

Comment: have you tried calling `cancel()` on the running Timer when it needs to be stopped?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. But it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reworked your `myTimer()` method and found that calling `cancel()` on the `Timer` instance (instead of the `TimerTask`) correctly stops the Timer. This happens because invoking `cancel()` on the `TimerTask` may cancel the task, but not the timer. The below code shows the class I used to test with.

```
public class TimerTest {
    public static final int TIMEOUT = 5;
    private static Timer timer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Creates and starts the Timer. The TimerTask cancels the Timer when
        // it's done, so we don't need to keep a reference to it.
        timer = myTimer(TIMEOUT);

        try {
            // Suppose the correct answer is given after 2.5 seconds
            Thread.sleep(2500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        timer.cancel();
        System.out.println("Timer interrupted by main");
    }

    public static Timer myTimer(final int timeout) {
        // We keep the Timer instance with the TimerTask, to prevent us from
        // having to worry about managing multiple timers. Each Timer is
        // guaranteed to stop when sec drops to 0.
        final Timer t = new Timer();
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            // We keep the current time in each TimerTask. This ensures that
            // multiple TimerTasks will not interfere with each other.
            private int sec = timeout;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sec--;
                if (sec < 0) {
                    t.cancel(); // cancel the Timer here.
                    System.out.println("Timer stopped by TimerTask");
                } else {
                    // Replace this with whatever you do each second
                    System.out.println("Current time: " + (sec < 10 ? "0" : "") + sec + " seconds");
                }
            }
        };
        t.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 1000);
        return t;
    }
}
```

Running the example starts a Timer, and then stops it after 2.5 seconds (this also exits the JVM, as there are no more running Threads). Changing `t.cancel()` in the TimerTask to `this.cancel()` seems to cancel the task (nothing is printed anymore), but fails to cancel the timer (the JVM keeps running).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a way to safely stop the thread. Check out this option: [The Safe Way to Stop a Thread by Bruce Eckel](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Threads/Thesafewaytostopathread.htm). This way you can call requestStop on the timer thread that's running, then start a new thread. You will have to save a reference to every timer thread you kick off so you can call the .requestStop method on it later.

Comment: I have implemented the class that you have given its link into my project. However, I have no idea about how to call to start and stop from my main class.